# Better syntax highlighting for Geany

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, geany, scintilla

I've recently started using a lightweight IDE called Geany. It's really efficient, very light on resources and has all the basic functionality I need. It has built in syntax highlighting for lots of programming languages including C++ which I'm coding in, however some of the highlighting doesn't seem to function properly.

[image: this screenshot I took]

Looking at the above screenshot I took, you can see that there is some syntax highlighting going, however the user declared function "addition" has no colouring applied to it, even after changing its colour in the configuration files. I found out that when I change the colour of "operator" in the configuration file, it changes every semicolon, bracket etc. to that colour, so clearly the dectection there isn't great.

I think this issue is due to the way the syntax highlighter works, which I believe is scintilla looking at the Geany GitHub source files. Here is the lexer file specifically for C++: https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/master/scintilla/lexers/LexCPP.cxx

I have a few questions:

1. Can the lexer file for C++ be updated with a better one so it can actually detect user defined functions as well as other parts of the language?
2. Is there a way of viewing all the different syntax's that scintilla picks up on (string, operator, preprocessor etc.)?
3. Are there any better syntax highlighters that could be possibly integrated into Geany?

Comment: Please use the `Stackoverflow` editor instead of positing code with an image...

Comment: @Peter. The question is about syntax highlighting in the Geany IDE, not the actual code itself. Using the SO editor would completely defeat the purpose.

Comment: (1) No. (2) See: `/usr/share/geany/filedefs/`, (3) No. (PS: the cpp lexer does not parse function names separately - the nearest you can get is "identifier", which , like "operator", will colour *all* identifiers).

Comment: @ekhumoro It actually looks like someone managed to mess around with the lexer file to add function detection: https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1231. But thanks for linking the list!

Comment: Well, yes, of course Geany and Scintilla are open source, so it's always possible to patch them. Was that really what you were asking? I didn't bother pointing that out, because I thought it was self-evidient. Anyway, Geany is tied to Scintilla as far as syntax highlighting is concerned, so you will always be limited to what it can provide - unless you are willing to contribute patches, or [write your own lexer](http://www.scintilla.org/Lexer.txt).

Comment: well… = is an operator, a self defined function is none. Please report a feature request to scintilla.

Answer (score 2):

I made an external plugin that enable surgical filetype editing, with color selectors.

https://github.com/webdev23/Geany-editor-dynamic-color-schemes

It is dynamically editing the `filetypes.xml` config.

Thinking to make the capability to import highlight themes from some other editor. Doable from this base.

[image]

---

Otherwise, one line install + all plugins, all themes, config completions:

```
sudo apt install geany geany-plugins &&
curl -o geany-themes-master.zip https://codeload.github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes/zip/master && unzip geany-themes-master.zip && cd geany-themes-master && ./install.sh &&
curl -o geany16.zip https://codeload.github.com/RobLoach/base16-geany/zip/master && unzip geany16.zip && echo -e "Config written. Close Geany to apply." > ~/info_geany.txt && cd base16-geany-master && find . -type f -name "*.conf" -exec cp -n {} ~/.config/geany/colorschemes/ \; &&
geany ~/info_geany.txt && rm ~/info_geany.txt && sed -i 's/autocomplete_doc_words=false/autocomplete_doc_words=true/' ~/.config/geany/geany.conf && sed -i 's/pref_editor_tab_width=4/pref_editor_tab_width=2/' ~/.config/geany/geany.conf && sed -i 's/symbolcompletion_min_chars=4/symbolcompletion_min_chars=2/' ~/.config/geany/geany.conf && sed -i 's/pref_editor_tab_width=4/pref_editor_tab_width=2/' ~/.config/geany/geany.conf && sed -i 's/color_scheme=/color_scheme=base16-atelierlakeside.dark.conf/' ~/.config/geany/geany.conf && echo "Install done."
```